403 insufficient insufficient authentication scopes when sending df to GSgeets
I have a script that collects data from an API and sends it to Google Sheets. However, every time I run it I get the 403 insufficient auth scopes error. My service account has Editor and Viewer roles, I even added Owner permissions for testing purposes but the code still fails with the same error. I have service account json in the same folder as my script thus i assumed the path is pretty straightforward. Google Sheets API enabled. What could be wrong?
import gspread
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials
import os

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "service_account.json"

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

creds = Credentials.from_service_account_file(os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"], scopes=SCOPES)

gc = gspread.authorize(creds)

worksheet = gc.open("spreadsheet_name")
sheet1 = worksheet.sheet1
sheet1.update([df.columns.values.tolist()] + df.fillna('').values.tolist())


On which environment are you?

IAM (e.g. "Editor and Viewer roles") only applies to Google Cloud services not Google Workspace services (e.g. Sheets). Google Workspace services, because they provide access to (individual) user-owned data (requiring user consent) cannot generally (!) be accessed by Service Accounts.  You've (limited) choices: either use a human user OAuth flow (e.g. Gmail account) or use domain-wide delegation but this must be with paid Google Workspace

An alternative is that you create a spreadsheet and add the mail of the service account as editor of it (like you'll do with any other user). The limitation is that it will work only on sheets where you grant permissions to the SA. As well this is risky in some way because if someone else access the SA they can get access to that data.

This is kinda tricky, the gspread lib require sheets and drive api access since the first one will allow you to handle the sheet and the second the object within drive
scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
]

Keep in mind that the API should be enabled on your GCP project
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/enable-api
That being said I had the chance to try the lib gspread and find that there are some issues so I ran this code using the 5.12 version and it worked fine
import gspread
gc = gspread.service_account('{credentials.json}')
sh = gc.create("Example spreadsheet2")
sh.share('{user@account}', perm_type='user', role='writer')
sh.add_worksheet(title="A worksheet", rows=100, cols=20)

gspread seem to handle all the authentication process just needs you to enable the API's
https://docs.gspread.org/en/v6.0.0/oauth2.html
